# What is the correct Dim-type and why is my macro getting slower?

Tags: excel, vba, performance, variable-declaration

I have an Excel-macro that basically works just fine for most of the cases, but there are three issues that bug me.

The code is a bit longer so I've reduced it to address the issues: (The issues are also marked in my code.)

Nr.1: When `uniqueArray` consists of more than one entry, the `Dim` for `item` and `uniqueArray` are fine. But when I've tested the unlikely case that `uniqueArray` consists of only one entry, I got the error, that the types don't match. I'm usally not programming stuff in Excel, so I'm not really familiar with the different types in vba. Do I need arrays here or can I just change the `Dim`?

Nr.2: The code gets slower and slower, the more sheets are added to the workbook by the macro. Is that normal behaviour, or can I speed up my code a bit?

Nr.3: A few years ago I had an issue with a slow macro. Then I found the hint with a forced pause. I've tried it with this macro again, and it improved the speed by a huuuge amount of time. How come a pause speeds up a macro?

```
   Sub Three_Issues()
    Dim ColumnLetter As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim sheetCount, TotalRow, TotalCol As Integer
    'Dim item, uniqueArray As Variant
    Dim item, uniqueArray() As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Get unique brands:
    With Sheets("Brand")
    .Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
    Sheets("Sales").Columns("R:R").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=.Range("A1"), Unique:=True
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'uniqueArray = .Range("A3:A" & lastRow)
    'Update:
    If .Range("A3:A" & lastRow).Cells.Count = 1 Then
    ReDim uniqueArray(1, 1)
    uniqueArray(1, 1) = .Range("A3")
    Else
    uniqueArray = .Range("A3:A" & lastRow).Value
    End With

    TotalRow = Sheets("Sales").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    TotalCol = Sheets("Sales").UsedRange.Columns.Count
    ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, TotalCol).Address, "$")(1) 'Num2Char
    sheetCount = 0 'Counter for statusbar

For Each item In uniqueArray 'item=Brand
'->Issue 1: Runtimer error 13 Types don't match: This happens if the uniqueArray consists of only one brand.
'Then item is Variant/Empty and uniqueArray is Variant/String
'If uniqueArray consists of more than one brand - which is usually the case - it works fine.
'item=Variant/Empty uniqueArray=e.g. Variant/Variant(1 to 2, 1 to 1)
'Can I change the Dim statement to solve this special case, or do I need arrays maybe?

    'Filter sales for each brand:
    With Sheets("Sales")
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(TotalRow, TotalCol)).AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:=item
    End With

    With Sheets("Agents")
    'Delete old...
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown)).Clear
    '...and get new
    Sheets("Sales").Range(Sheets("Sales").Cells(3, 2), Sheets("Sales").Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    .Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

    'List with all agents
    For Each cell In Worksheets("Agents").Range("A2", Worksheets("Agents").Range("A1").End(xlDown))

    With Sheets("Report")
    .Range("I4") = cell 'Copy agent and update the formulas within the report
'->Issue 2: It takes around 10 seconds to fill 10 sheets with the reports of 10 agents.
'When I reach 70-80 sheets, it slows down to 30 seconds for 10 sheets.
'Is this just because of the number of sheets, or can I speed it up again?

    .Range(.PageSetup.PrintArea).Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets("Report")

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
        , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value 'Replace all formulas with values
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.Name = cell

    sheetCount = sheetCount + 1
    If sheetAnz Mod 10 = 0 Then Application.StatusBar = sheetAnz 'Get statusupdate every 10 sheets
    End With
    Next

'->Issue 3: I create up to 400 sheets and when I want to continue and do some sorting of the sheets for example it takes a very long time.
'But if I add this break for a second, it works reasonably fine again. Why is that? Does vba needs the break to catch up with itself?
'Since the issue is not the sorting and the other stuff after the pause.

 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")) 'Code becomes faster after that...

    'Continue with other stuff.... sorting sheets and so on

Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Any ideas on one of the issues?

Comment: See http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx - just one cell is a special case if you want to read the range value into an array.

Comment: I usually create a UDF to test if range is one cell or many and have it return proper array accordingly. WHen you try to set a array equal to a single cell you just end up with a value, not an array which is the type mismatch

Answer (score 0):

You can output a array with 1 value or multiple values using the below `UDF`. *This would benefit from also passing along a worksheet variable so objects can be properly qualified*

---

Call the function from your current macro like so

```
uniqueArray = MyArr(lastrow)
```

---

```
Public Function MyArr(lastrow As Long) As Variant

If Range("A3:A" & lastrow).Cells.Count = 1 Then
    ReDim MyArr(1, 1)
    MyArr(1, 1) = Range("A3")
Else
    MyArr = Range("A3:A" & lastrow).Value
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Ok, I think I've added your suggestion to my code, but now 'item' stays empty in the case of only one entry although 'uniqueArray' is correctly filled with this one entry.

Comment: That is a different issue and deserves it's own question. **SPECIFIC** questions get **SPECIFIC** answers. You can't post 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 problems and expect us to answer each one in one post. Search how to loop through an array (hint: `UBOUND`, `LBOUND`) and then post another question if you get stuck

Comment: I wasn't sure if I should make one question or more out of it. Seems I got it wrong. ;) I'll check your hint, thanks.